# Generate issue links in Jira with scriptrunner

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk, scriptrunner-for-jira

I am trying to generate some issue links in jira, here is my code. This code is executed as a Jira automation rule after clicking on a button.  The problem is that I receive the following error message. They say that the issuelinktype is wrong, anyone knows how to figure out which issue link type I need?

[image]
package SuperFeature
import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager

import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexManager

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkManager

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexingService

def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')

log.warn("MOUNA: ")

log.warn("MOUNA COMPONENT NUMBERS : "+ issue.getComponents().size())

List<String> componentList = new ArrayList<String>()

def authenticationContext = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext

if (issue.getComponents().size()==0){

    issue.update {

    String text= "Issue does not have any components\n"

    setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)

    }

}else if(issue.getFixVersions().size()==0){

            issue.update {

                String text= "Issue does not have any fix versions\n"

                setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)

                }

    

}

else{

        int componentSize=issue.getComponents().size()

        for(ProjectComponent component : issue.getComponents()) {

                componentList.add(component.getName())

        }

        issue.update {

            String text= "The super feature "+issue+" will be split into "+componentSize+

            " features, one for each component:\n"

            for(String component: componentList){

                text = text +"-"+ component+"\n"; 

            }

            setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)

}

// Issue issue

def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.issueManager

def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.issueFactory

def subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.subTaskManager

def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager

def userManager = ComponentAccessor.userManager

// Defining subtask

def newIssue = issueFactory.getIssue()

newIssue.setParentId(issue.getId())

log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA issue.getId()"+ issue.getId())

def Long issueLinkType = new Long (10001)

def Long sequence = new Long (1)

newIssue.setProjectObject(issue.getProjectObject())

newIssue.setSummary("MOUNA CAMELIA")

newIssue.setAssignee(userManager.getUserByName("mouh"))

newIssue.setDescription(issue.getDescription())

                for(String component: componentList){

                    def subTask = issueManager.createIssueObject(authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser(), newIssue)

                    subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, subTask, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())

                    issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(issue.getId(), newIssue.getId(), issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MutableIssue newissue= ComponentAccessor.issueFactory.getIssue()
          
 def newIssueCreated = issueManager.createIssueObject(currentUserObj, newissue)
               
 issueLinkManager.createIssueLink(newIssueCreatedID, myissueID, issueLinkType, sequence, authenticationContext.getLoggedInUser())
```